# How to remove an old domain name and add a new domain name on a server?

Tags: domain, vps

I have a VPS with the domain name `sample.net`.  We want to change it to `sample.com`.  It's a live server.  I have purchased the sample.com domain.

I have VPS CPANEL, so what is the best process/option to remove and add domains on the same
host?

How do I go about doing this?  I have very little knowledge in server administration so any advice you guys have is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely check with the hosting provider if they have a FAQ to know more about how to remove or add a domain name on their hosting platform. It's important to determine if their CPANEL also automatically handles the Apache vHosts configuration or not (very important since it could cause your site to go down!). It's fine to contact their Support team as well to get more details about such common site maintenance.

One thing you'll have to do is to retrieve your server's IP address. This will allow you to create an A record with your DNS provider and thus be in a position to direct traffic for sample.com to your VPS. Also, be careful about how you're gonna set up your domain names with your DNS provider. Do NOT allow traffic from different domain names on the same site. This causes [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) and is very bad for your SEO.

Beyond the technical changes and possible SEO issues that such major change implies, make sure to have working redirects in place for all your URLs - I'd recommend you leverage Google Webmaster Tools on the one hand and check your Apache log files for 404s on the other hand in order to spot them early and fix any broken link.

So, what I'd do is to create a "DNS visible redirect" if your provider allows for that. This is basically a feature that allows to redirect one domain to another. The point is NOT that you simply wipe out the deprecated domain but that you redirect it transparently to sample.com instead. Else, you can leverage an Apache .htaccess redirect such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above .htaccess redirect will ensure that all sample.net traffic coming to your Apache server gets redirected to the sample.com domain instead. If you want to know more about 301 redirects, please read https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Keep in mind that this whole maintenance is involved and you didn't give enough information on your specific challenges to proceed from A to Z without problems. The above recommendations should hopefully clarify a few things already.